# Type annotate an S3 bucket

Tags: boto3, mypy

To satisfy our linter, I need to type annotate a bucket.  We use the `boto3-stubs` library for this, but I can't find how to do it.

I want to do something like:

```py
def delete_from_bucket(old_bucket: Bucket, key: str) -> None:
    old_bucket.delete_key(key)
```

How can I annotate the `old_bucket` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Because the [boto3-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/) library was built on the [mypy-boto3](https://pypi.org/project/mypy-boto3/) library, it still retains the mypy-boto3 imports.

[Docs for Bucket service resource](https://youtype.github.io/boto3_stubs_docs/mypy_boto3_s3/service_resource/#bucket)

```py
from mypy_boto3_s3.service_resource import Bucket
def delete_from_bucket(old_bucket: Bucket, key: str) -> None:
    old_bucket.delete_key(key)
```

This works with IntelliSense to prompt with method suggestions, so hopefully this will satisfy the linter's requirements.